# Many to Many relationship Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have 2 Tables in my Postgres DB. One contains multiple states from different part of the World and the other one contains postal code that are in those states.

They're multiple postal code in one city. But postal code are only link to a single city.

Here an example of my 2 tables :

States :

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| pk |   state    | city      |         city_id       |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Montreal   | Quebec    |          123          |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2 | Laval      | Quebec    |          123          |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3 | Ottawa     | Ontario   |          837          |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Postal Code :

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| pk |Postal Code | city      |         city_id       |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | H1H1H1     | Quebec    |          123          |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  2 | H4P2T5     | Quebec    |          123          |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  3 | G1G2G2     | Ontario   |          837          |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

I am using django autocomplete-light for my input and now I want to Forward my states to filter my Postal Code with the city_id field.

The problem that I have is that Django errors tell me :

```
'stateModel.city_id' must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key.
```

when I try to use Foreign key which is not unique because the same City might be use in different state. And I got this errror when I try to use ManyToMany

```
ERREUR:  la relation « postalCodeModel_city_id » n'existe pas
LINE 1: ...COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "postalCodeModel" INNER JOIN "postalCodeModel...
```

when I try to create a one to many field or send the pk by default if i choose the ManyToManyField option.

**Is there a way to filter postal code with cities from state model? Do I need to create a City table and after that create a ManyToManyField with Trought option to this new table ?**

```
class stateModel(models.Model):
    idunique = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    city_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stateDB'


class codePostalModel(models.Model):
    cp_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #city_id_cp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    city_id_cp = models.ForeignKey(stateModel, to_field='city_id', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #city_id_cp = models.ManyToManyField(stateModel)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cp

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'postalCodeDB'
```

Comment: Why don't you just set `unique=True` on the field? A primary key should always be unique.

Comment: write your model please

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the reply. I might have reduce the code to much and create error. Every state has a unique pk, but I want to filter my postal code with  cities. Example I take Montreal i want to get every postal code that have a city_id of 123 and that field cannot be unique.